# Disable showing password input characters with a physical keyboard?

Tags: cyanogenmod, keyboard

I'm using a Google Nexus 7 2013 LTE running CyanogenMod 11.0M6.

When I use a physical bluetooth keyboard to type in password input fields, Android still displays one character at a time, which is a bit of a security concern.

Is there a way to disable this either globally (ie: even for soft keyboards) or specifically for external keyboards so that password characters are never shown as they are input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Settings, go to Security and uncheck "Make Passwords Visible." This will cause all password characters to be obfuscated, even as you type. It is a global option, so there is no way to set it for just one input method.

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay glad to help. It is always nice when it is a simple solution.